# The Concept of Charge in terms of Discrete and Continuous Distribution

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge, classical-electrodynamics

When we are studying Classical Electrodynamics, in Electrostatics we are considering a discrete charge (positive or negative) to be like a point particle and the electric lines of force are coming out from that charge or coming into the charge in all directions.

But, when we are again considering continuous charge distribution (linear/surface/volume) of the same discrete point charge in some geometrical shape of a physical body, then how can we consider a point charge be distributed all over the body?

I am unable to understand this concept to consider the discrete point charge concept and again continuous distribution of this same discrete point charge over to some geometrical shape.

How two of these cases can be understood with proper physical reasoning?

Comment: Are you sure you mean a single point charge distributed over a whole body and not a given charge of, lets say, $5C$ distributed over a whole body? Even if we know that $5C$ charge would ultimately be composed of elementary charges?

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  My interpretation is this:  How can we consider a real object to be a continuous charge distribution when in fact it comprises a collection of point charges?      Is this the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you want to know how to approximate a distribution of point charges, that is, a discrete distribution, with a continuous one.

A continuous distribution of charges can be generated by taking, for each point of the body or of the volume of interest, the average charge over a test volume containing many point charges. In more refined approaches, one can consider the asymptotic behaviour of the average density while enlarging the test volume.

In other words, one constructs the continuous distribution by weighing (averaging, smoothing) the discrete distribution with a *smooth* weighing function $\varphi(x)$, normalized so that
$$\int\varphi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 1.$$
This approach is, for instance, well described in G. Russakoff, ["A derivation of the macroscopic Maxwell equations"](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/38/10/10.1119/1.1976000), *Am. J. Phys.*, **38**, 1188. See also the derivation of the macroscopic Maxwell equations given by Jackson in his *Classical electrodynamics*.

**Disclaimer:** A few years ago, I asked on Math.SE a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1537534/159634), still unanswered, on how to formalize this process within measure theory. This answer is essentially the introduction to that question.

Comment: The smoothing does provide sources that are distributed in space, but it does not derive macroscopic Maxwell equations as they are commonly used. The problem is that macroscopic sources used there are not only more distributed in space than point charges, but they also carry much less information about the position of those point charges. This simplicity or lack of information is not captured by the integral transformation that Russakoff uses; in fact, for a simple, smooth smoothing function the integral transformation is reversible. It does not take away the positions of those point charges.